# Possible military aircraft ID, N. Carolina

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I was recently in Oak Island, NC and saw the following plane flying above. It was low-flying and much louder and larger than the other small prop planes flying out of nearby [Cape Fear Regional Jetport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Fear_Regional_Jetport). Based on the size of the propellers I suspected it was some kind of military aircraft but wasn't able to figure out what it was. I know this is a small, dark picture, but does this plane look familiar?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a [V-22 Osprey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey).  Here is a photo.  (it happens to be refueling, so ignore the nose hose.)

[image]

Comment: This is not a 3D render ?

Comment: @Antzi: Even if it is a render rather than an actual photo, what difference would it make? It shows an Osprey.

Comment: From the color, it looks like a CV-22. Definitely a V-22 though, and the differences are subtle.

Comment: Also, definitely a render. Some of the colors are wrong and the intakes are too clean.